# jQuery loop through same classname

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, loops

I have a few elements with the same class name `data` for example, they could look like this:

```
<p class="data">AAA</p>
<p class="data">BBB</p>
<p class="data">CCC</p>
<p class="data">DDD</p>
```

Now I want to loop through all the elements with class name `data` and see if any of them match a string, say `AAA`. If it does, then make that element red color.

```
$(".data").each(function() {
    if (this.val() == "AAA") {
        $(this).css("color", "red");
    }
});
```

However, this isn't working. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

p tag does not have any value, it has text and `$(this)` should be used to apply jquery functions, only `this` will not work.

```
$(".data").each(function() {
    if ($(this).text() == "AAA") {
        $(this).css("color", "red");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

`this` should be `$(this)` and `val()` should be `html()`. `val()` is used for elements with a value attribute like input fields and radio buttons ect. `html()` gets the html inside an element. `this` is the vanilla Javascripts version of jQuerys `$(this)`.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".data").each(function() {
        if ($(this).html() == "AAA") {
            $(this).css("color", "red");
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

No need to loop through the class name to achieve that result.
You can simply write

```
$('.data:contains("AAA")').css('background-color', 'red');
```

Note: This will only work if you are sure enough that other tags won't contain AAA. For example in following scenario it may not work.

```
<p class="data">AAA BBB</p>
<p class="data">AAA</p>
<p class="data">CCC</p>
<p class="data">DDD</p>
```

Comment: *`"it may not work"`* is unclear. Rather say that the element having `AAA BBB` **will** be targeted - since it actually contains *"...AAA..."*

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest:

```
// Select all '.data' elements, and filter that collection
// Using jQuery's filter() method:
$(".data").filter(

  // using an arrow function to retain only those
  // elements whose trimmed text-content is
  // equal to "AAA":
  (index, element) => $(element).text().trim() === "AAA"

// using the css() methods to set the color property to
// To 'red':
).css('color', 'red');
```

Comment: I can't believe I haven't heard of or used an arrow function before.  Thanks for prompting me to look up this syntax!

Answer (score 1):

### Using `filter()`

```js
$(".data").filter(function(i, el){
  return $(el).text() === "AAA"; 
}).css({color: "red"});
```

```html
<p class="data">AAA</p>
<p class="data">BBB</p>
<p class="data">CCC</p>
<p class="data">DDD</p>


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

### Using `.text()`

```js
$(".data").text(function(i, txt){
  if(txt==="AAA") $(this).css({color: "red"});
});
```

```html
<p class="data">AAA</p>
<p class="data">BBB</p>
<p class="data">CCC</p>
<p class="data">DDD</p>


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

use `$(this)` instead `this`

```js
$(".data").each(function() { 
  if ($(this).html() == "AAA") { 
    $(this).css("color", "red"); 
  } 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="data">AAA</p>
<p class="data">BBB</p>
<p class="data">CCC</p>
<p class="data">DDD</p>
```